# How Do I Get "Me" URLs Using a Daemon in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a Microsoft Teams daemon service app with application-level permissions. I can call GET on urls like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` and it works fine.

However, if I want to get something like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/onenote/notebooks/getRecentNotebooks`, I get `InvalidAccessToken` even though I have permissions enabled for it in my daemon app. I've tried eliminating the `me` from the url, replacing it with my tenant address, `users`, `users/uid`, `myOrganization`, etc, but I get Error 400 in those cases. No combination I've tried seems to work.

What is the proper format for calling urls like this for a daemon service app with application-level permissions?

Answer (score 1):

In an application context 'me' doesn't mean anything. There's no user authenticated so the access token doesn't give your application access from the viewpoint of a particular user.

Instead of /users/me/, call Graph with /users/user-guid/ or /users/user-principal-name. For example, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ce900c69-ac07-450a-ad2f-f56e42ee621e/onenote or https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jon@doe.com/onenote

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
[image]

Edit:
Also check out the Graph explorer for samples like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tried `users/{uid}` as well (I've updated my question to include it) but I still get a 400 error. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Can you post the request id and timestamp of that call so I can take a look? (Request id is returned from Graph in the response headers). Thanks

Comment: I can, but I've never done that before. I have two questions first: 1) how does it help you, and 2) is it secure? (I need to make sure the `uid` or content etc can't be extracted as a result of the request id)

Comment: Also, is there a way to get all notebooks etc for an organization, or only by iterating through all users?

Comment: Posting the request id is safe and officially documented on the Microsoft Graph documentation website - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/best-practices-concept#reliability-and-support "Always log the request-id, timestamp and x-ms-ags-diagnostic from the HTTP response headers. These, together with the client-request-id, are required when reporting issues in Stack Overflow or to Microsoft Support.".

Comment: Yes, it's secure and the request id & timestamp lets Microsoft Graph engineers safely debug the request without seeing any customer data. To everyone else in the public looking at this thread it will just be a random guid that they can't extract data from.

Comment: Good to know. I think it might be the url? For instance:
`GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{uid}/onenote/notebooks"`
works, but not `GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{uid}/onenote/notebooks/getRecentNotebooks(includePersonalNotebooks=true)"`, even though it's documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/notebook-getrecentnotebooks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http